# Vue.js child component with object literals as props unexpectedly updates when its parent renders

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got several Vue components passed with some object literals as props like

```html
<child :prop1="{ foo: 'bar' }"></child>
```

However, when parent component rerenders, as the minimal codesandbox example below shows, `prop1` changes (detected by watcher) and causes `Child` to update. If the prop is an object reference, it stays unchanged.

Why does this happen and does it mean it may not be 'safe' to use object literals(and perhaps array literal) as props?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jj0tb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time the template runs it will create a new object when it hits that section. The same would apply to any reference type, so arrays, functions, etc.

It's similar to objects, etc. that are created in JavaScript code. e.g.

```js
function getObject() {
    return {};
}

console.log(getObject() === getObject()); // false
```

Each time `getObject` is called it will return a new object and object equality is based on reference and not whether the objects contain the same values. This is effectively what Vue does when checking for changed props. Remember that a Vue template is compiled down to a `render` function and that's just plain JavaScript. Any object literals will still be object literals in that `render` function.

In the case of your example the render function for the parent would look something like this, assuming there's nothing else in the template:

```js
function render(h) {
    return h('child', {
        props: {
            prop1: {foo: 'bar'}
        }
    })
}
```

So each time it runs there'll be a new object for `prop1`.

As you've already mentioned, moving the object to your `data` and then referencing it by name will ensure that the same object is used each time, avoiding the child updates.

Whether it's worth worrying about will depend on the specifics of your scenario but it can have performance implications if there are enough children being updated like this. The child rendering shouldn't need to update the actual DOM but any computed properties, watches or templates will run if they rely on that prop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's much more obvious to tell what's happening with a render function.